xmodmap key remap doesn't work
I remapped ESC to grave (`) using xmodmap and xev shows that ESC is indeed mapped to grave but outside of xev it didn't take effect, it's still ESC. Couldn't find anyone online that had this exact problem.
Screenshot
Is there another layer between what xev reads and the client layer? I thought what xev reads is sent directly to the client.
I have done these exact steps right beforehand on a different machine and it worked perfectly fine so it's not an issue of false execution.
Help appreciated <3

Esc is usually defined by the system - you would probably need to remap it it in every application you use to be effective in the way you expect (and some apps may not even allow it). The grave key in my system is selected simply by pressing thecomposekey (whichever one you have selected) which latches then pressing the top most left key belowescwhen using it to create a char combined with the grave character such as in the case of è for example. Pressed on it's own, it will still produce the backtick key. My keyboard is set to English (UK) for reference

@graham I have a 60% keyboard and I don't have a dedicated key for grave, I use caps lock for ESC (for VIM). I can use FN + ESC for grave, but that is very tedious because for tilde I have to press FN + shift + ESC. And like I said, this exact thing has worked on my other ubuntu machine.
